# Combine Google Maps image overlay (with .svg) with watch position?

Tags: javascript, google-maps, svg

I was playing around with this part of the Google Maps image overlay code:

```
var overlay;
USGSOverlay.prototype = new google.maps.OverlayView();

// Initialize the map and the custom overlay.

function initialize() {
    var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 11,
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(62.323907, -150.109291),
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE
    };

    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map-canvas'), mapOptions);

    var swBound = new google.maps.LatLng(62.281819, -150.287132);
    var neBound = new google.maps.LatLng(62.400471, -150.005608);
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds(swBound, neBound);

    // The photograph is courtesy of the U.S. Geological Survey.
    var srcImage = 'example.svg'; // it works with an png/jpg but not with svg ?

    // The custom USGSOverlay object contains the USGS image,
    // the bounds of the image, and a reference to the map.
    overlay = new USGSOverlay(bounds, srcImage, map);
}

/** @constructor */
function USGSOverlay(bounds, image, map) {

    // Initialize all properties.
    this.bounds_ = bounds;
    this.image_ = image;
    this.map_ = map;

    // Define a property to hold the image's div. We'll
    // actually create this div upon receipt of the onAdd()
    // method so we'll leave it null for now.
    this.div_ = null;

    // Explicitly call setMap on this overlay.
    this.setMap(map);
}


USGSOverlay.prototype.onAdd = function() {

    var div = document.createElement('div');
    div.style.borderStyle = 'none';
    div.style.borderWidth = '0px';
    div.style.position = 'absolute';

    // Create the img element and attach it to the div.
    var img = document.createElement('img');
    img.src = this.image_;
    img.style.width = '100%';
    img.style.height = '100%';
    img.style.position = 'absolute';
    div.appendChild(img);

    this.div_ = div;

    // Add the element to the "overlayLayer" pane.
    var panes = this.getPanes();
    panes.overlayLayer.appendChild(div);
};

USGSOverlay.prototype.draw = function() {


    var overlayProjection = this.getProjection();


    var sw = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getSouthWest());
    var ne = overlayProjection.fromLatLngToDivPixel(this.bounds_.getNorthEast());

    // Resize the image's div to fit the indicated dimensions.
    var div = this.div_;
    div.style.left = sw.x + 'px';
    div.style.top = ne.y + 'px';
    div.style.width = (ne.x - sw.x) + 'px';
    div.style.height = (sw.y - ne.y) + 'px';
};

// The onRemove() method will be called automatically from the API if
// we ever set the overlay's map property to 'null'.
USGSOverlay.prototype.onRemove = function() {
    this.div_.parentNode.removeChild(this.div_);
    this.div_ = null;
};

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

I tried to integrate an `.svg` image instead of an "normal" image-type, but i am not sure if this is possible because when i change it to svg nothing is shown, just the outlines of the svg (depending on the used browser), or do i have to integrate the whole svg-xml code to the side itself?
Another point it's to combine the code above with watchPosition (or watchID).
Is this generally possible and do i have to override the `LatLng` with my geolocal position?

```
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(callback, errorCallback, {enableHighAccuracy:true, timeout:5000, maximumAge:60000});
```

...appreciate for some help